# Timezone não funciona PHP

Tags: php, timezone

Quando dou o comando: `echo ini.get('date.timezone') . "<br>";` não aparece nada, já configurei no **php.ini** e nada, também já coloquei o **default** no código e nada também. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual versão do PHP está usando? Já tentou:
`echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';`

Comment: Links que podem ajudar: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php e http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao meu ver é um erro de sintaxe :

Substitua `ini.get('date.timezone')` por `ini_get('date.timezone');`

Exemplo :

```
<?php
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
?>
```

Comment: Nossa só era a sintaxe mesmo sou bem iniciante ainda. Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Quem não passou por isso, não evoluiu, desistiu, certeza... estamos ai...

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Quando erros de sintaxe acontecem eles são reportados em tela, caso não apareça na tela eles ficam armazenados em logs, esses dados são muito úteis para resolver problemas ou para fazer questionamentos para terceiros que não tem acesso ao projeto.

Em qual ambiente você está desenvolvendo o sistema? Como aparentemente o erro de sintaxe não foi reportado em tela provavelmente o PHP esta configurado para não exibir, caso isso seja em ambiente de produção está correto, mas caso seja em ambiente de desenvolvimento ou de teste esta "errado", pois é bom que o programador tome conhecimento dos problemas na aplicação.

## Como verificar os logs de erro do PHP/Apache em um sistema Linux (Debian ou derivados):

Abra o terminal e de o comando `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` esse comando ficara monitorando o arquivo de erros do Apache assim a cada teste aparecerá as novas informações inserida no log, para ficar mais claro as coisas a cada teste você pode pressionar a tecla `Enter` para abrir um espaço entre o último erro e o próximo para visualização ficar mais simples. Esses espaços (Enters) não seram salvos no Log. Para sair basta precional `Ctrl + c`;

## Como verificar os logs de erro do PHP em Windows:

**WAMP**: Siga os passos:

1 - *Clique com o botão direito do mouse no icone do wamp perto do relógio*

2 - *Acesse o submenu PHP*

3 - *E clique em PHP Error Log*

Dessa forma você terá que recarregar o arquivo toda vez que fizer um novo teste, utilizando o Sublime Text 3 para abrir esse log ele identificará uma mudança no conteúdo do arquivo e perguntará se você deseja recarregá-lo, clicando em `sim` ele atualizará pra você.

**XAMP**: da mesma forma que no WAMP

**Obs.:** caso tenha instalado o Apache e PHP direto é só dar uma pesquisada rápida na net que acha fácil. Porém nunca vi ninguém instalando de forma 
direta.

## Configurando o PHP pra reportar erros em um sistema Linux (Debian ou derivados):

Abra o arquivo `php.ini` aqui esta localizado em `/etc/php/5.5/apache2/php.ini` localize as seguintes linhas ou adicione no final do arquivo

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

A opção `error_reporting` define o tipo do nível de erros que será reportado, `E_ALL` reportará todos. Não é legal reportar erros em ambiente de produção já que usuários maus intencionados poderão e vão utilizar essas informações para invadir seu sistema. Em ambiente de desenvolvimento e teste é altamente recomendável `E_ALL` para não deixar nenhum erro passar para o ambiente de produção.

A opção `display_errors` define se os erros serão reportados em tela, caso queria coloque `on` depois do sinal de igual caso não queira coloque `off`

A opção `log_errors` define se os erros serão reportados no log, caso queria coloque `on` depois do sinal de igual caso não queira coloque `off`

**Essa forma de configuração se aplica também a ambiente Windows já que é uma particularidade do PHP, o que muda é apenas o caminho do arquivo**, isso em suposição pois não trabalho desenvolvendo em Windows mas sim no Linux, já que meus sistemas ficam hospedados em Linux.

Comment: Complete sua resposta, Indicando uma forma de verificar isso... Acho que é relevante o que está propondo...

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo no NetBeans, testei outro código só que propositalmente errado e sinalizou sim, apenas o da minha pergunta que não foi sinalizado.

Comment: @MagicHat certo completarei...
RodolfoAllesson no caso estais usando Windows e ambiente de desenvolvimento, certo? Então já que você testou outro erro de sintaxe e o PHP retornou o erro, o que aconteceu no seu caso pode estar fora dos erros que são reportados. Vou completar minha resposta e colocarei como verificar isso.

Comment: @MateusFMello Na verdade estou utilizando o Ubuntu, mas testei em outra maquina com Windows e aconteceu o mesmo, já agradeço pela resposta amigo.

Comment: @RodolfoAllesson fico feliz em ver isso, então minhas dicas que acabei de passar na minha resposta te ajudarão bastante, lembrando que Ubuntu é derivado de Debian, então imagino que você não terá nenhum problema em executar as dicas caso ache necessário. E não esquece de pontuar como resposta positiva para dar uma força :D

Comment: @MateusFMello Muito obrigado pelas dicas amigos, foram muito valiosas para mim, você já é mestre kkk.